# Как вернуть ResultSet? JAVA

Tags: java

Как вернуть `ResultSet`?

Мой код:

```
public ResultSet getUser(String nickname,String password){
    ResultSet resSet = null;

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM dvsusers WHERE username=? AND password=?";

    try (PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(sql)) {

      prSt.setString(1, nickname);
      prSt.setString(2, password);

      resSet = prSt.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
      return resSet;
  }
```

Comment: скорее всего "A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results" ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)), поэтому просто так взять и вернуть `ResultSet` нельзя.

Comment: А как вернуть то? Я знаю что просто нельзя.

Comment: Как я понял. Нужно сначала достать данные с ResultSet а потом уже передавать. А как это сделать так и не понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как было написано выше, просто так вернуть ResultSet нельзя, но это можно сделать через кэширование его данных в CachedRowSet

```
public ResultSet getUser(String nickname, String password) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet resSet = null;

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM dvsusers WHERE username=? AND password=?";

        try (PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(sql)) {

            prSt.setString(1, nickname);
            prSt.setString(2, password);

            resSet = prSt.executeQuery();

        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
        CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = factory.createCachedRowSet();
        cachedRowSet.populate(resSet);
        return cachedRowSet;
    }
```

Comment: Не получается сделать как вы описали в ответе. Ошибка находиться вот тут - .newFactory(); вот тут - createCachedRowSet(); и вот тут - createCachedRowSet(); . Подчеркивает красным.